# How to query a bag with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, subquery

I need to get publications which the country list doesn't contain a country (research on IsoCode2)

The sql query is :

```
select * from pub_head ph
where not exists
(select 1 from pub_head_forbidden_country phfc , country c
                where phfc.pub_head_id = ph.pub_head_id 
                and phfc.country_id = c.country_id 
                and c.iso_code2 = 'CA');
```

And the model :

```
<class name="Publication" table="PUB_HEAD">

  <id name="Id" column="PUB_HEAD_ID">
   <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">SEQ_PUB_HEAD</param>
   </generator>
  </id>

  <idbag name="Countries" table="PUB_HEAD_COUNTRY" lazy="true">
   <collection-id column="PUB_HEAD_COUNTRY_ID">
    <generator class="native">
     <param name="sequence">SEQ_PUB_HEAD_COUNTRY</param>
    </generator>
   </collection-id>

   <key column ="PUB_HEAD_ID"  />
   <many-to-many class="Model.Referential.Country, Model" column="COUNTRY_ID"/>
  </idbag>
</class>

<class name="Country" table="Country">
  <id name="Id" column="COUNTRY_ID">
   <generator class="native">
   </generator>
  </id>
  <property name="Name">
   <column name="NAME"></column>
  </property>
  <property name="IsoCode2">
   <column name="ISO_CODE2"></column>
  </property>
  <property name="IsoCode3">
   <column name="ISO_CODE3"></column>
  </property>

 </class>
```

I began with SubQueries, but I didn't success to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do the query in hql or with the criteria api? And whats that pub_head_forbidden_country table in the sql query you posted?

Comment: the pub_head_forbidden_country table is like pub_head_country table (sorry for the copy/paste)

Comment: I don't see pub_head_forbidden_country mapped in your model. If it's not mapped, you can't query it using NHibernate. Are you saying that you have a Publication.ForbiddenCountries collection that you omitted from the example?

Answer (score 0):

Allergic to joins? That SQL is very hard to understand.

Does it mean this?

```
SELECT *
FROM pub_head
WHERE id not IN (
  SELECT phfc.pub_head_id
  FROM pub_head_forbidden_country as phfc
    INNER JOIN country AS c ON phfc.country_id = c.country_id
  WHERE c.iso_code2 = 'CA'
)
```

*[Posting as answer because this SQL would be awful in a comment.]*

Comment: Yes, i'm allergic to joins ;)

Comment: Isn't the query much more semantic and much less confusing like this? Or maybe my brain is just weak and lazy. :) [Btw: I'd try answering, but I have no idea how to solve your problem.]

Answer (score 0):

The Sql could be like this too

```
SELECT * FROM pub_head ph
WHERE ph.pub_head_id not IN (
  SELECT phfc.pub_head_id
  FROM pub_head_forbidden_country phfc
    INNER JOIN country  c ON phfc.country_id = c.country_id
  WHERE c.iso_code2 = 'CA'
)
```